# C++ Linked List Sorting, Splitting, and Printing issue

Tags: c++, sorting, split, linked-list, printf

Hi guys for my lab assignment this week I was assigned to learn about Linked Lists. The lab prompt is as follows:

1. Write a program that creates a forward linked list of at least 20 elements, where each element holds a random integer between 0 and 99. Print the list.
2. Write the function "returnMiddleList" to find the middle element of the linked list in one pass. Print the integer value of this element and the position of this element (starting at zero) in relation to the head (where the head = 0, the element pointed to by the head = 1, the element pointed to by the previous one = 2, etc).
3. Split the list in half at the middle element to create two entirely separate* linked lists of near equal size (+/- 1) and print the two lists. Modify the "returnMiddleList" function to accomplish this, returning the head of the second linked list and setting the link of the element pointing to that head to null. Then print the two sums of the integers stored in the elements of both lists.
4. Sort the two lists from least to greatest and print them out (printing at this step is optional depending on the sort approach taken). Then combine the two lists while sorting them again from least to greatest and print out the new list. (HINT: you can subdivide the lists further and sort them on a scale of one to two element lists before sorting and combining the first two unsorted lists. What is this sort called?)

I have got #1 and #2 working, but #3 and #4 is where the issue is beginning. When I split my link list into two lists and print the individual lists out, my first link list prints out 9 numbers when it should be printing out 10 (the 10th number somehow disappears?), but when I do the sum of the first list right after that, the number that has disappeared gets added in the sum! I do not know why it is disappearing, and this is one issue. Another issue is in the second list, a random "0" gets added to the list and one of the numbers is lost. My last issue is about #4 as the merge algorithm I have used does not seem to work (I am merging the list together while sorting them, but I am not using a recursion sort because we have not learned that yet). Any input and help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

struct nodeType {
    int data;
    nodeType *link;
};

void populateList(nodeType *head) {
//  srand(time(NULL));
    nodeType *temp;
    nodeType *current = head;

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        temp = new nodeType;

        current->data = rand() % 100;

        current->link = temp;

        current = temp;
    }

    temp->link = NULL;
}

void print(nodeType *head) {
    int i = 1;

    while (head->link != NULL) {
        cout << "#" << i++ << ": " << head->data << endl;

        head = head->link;
    }
}

nodeType* returnMiddleList(nodeType *head) {
    nodeType *p1 = head, *p2 = head;
    int count = 0;
    int middle = 1;

    while (p1->link->link != NULL) {
        p1 = p1->link;

        count++;

        if (count % 2 == 0) {
            p2 = p2->link;
            middle++;
        }

    }

    cout << "Middle #" << middle << ": " << p2->data << endl;

    p1 = p2->link;
    p2->link = NULL;

    return p1;
}

void add(nodeType *head) {
    int sum = 0;

    while (head != NULL) {
        sum = sum + head->data;
        head = head->link;
    }

    cout << sum << endl;
}

void sort(nodeType *head) {
    nodeType *temp = head;

    while (temp != NULL) {
        nodeType *temp2 = temp;

        while (temp2 != NULL) {
            if (temp->data > temp2->data) {
                int temp3;

                temp3 = temp->data;
                temp->data = temp2->data;
                temp2->data = temp3;
            }

            temp2 = temp2->link;
        }

        temp = temp->link;
    }
}

nodeType* merge(nodeType* head1, nodeType* head2) {
    nodeType *head3 = new nodeType, *current1 = head1, *current2 = head2;

    while (current1 != NULL || current2 != NULL) {
        if (current1 == NULL) {
            while (current2 != NULL) {
                //logic
                current2 = current2->link; //dumps list 2
                head3->data = current2->data;
            }
            break;
        }
        if (current2 == NULL) {
            while (current1 != NULL) {
                //Logic
                current1 = current1->link; //dumps list 1
                head3->data = current1->data;
            }
            break;
        }

        if (current1->data < current2->data) {
            //logic
            current1 = current1->link; //increments list 1
            head3->data = current1->data;

        } else {
            //logic
            current2 = current2->link; //increments list 2
            head3->data = current2->data;

        }

    }

    return head3;
}

int main() {
    nodeType *head = new nodeType, *head2, *head3;

    populateList(head);

    print(head);
    cout << endl;

    head2 = returnMiddleList(head);

    cout << endl << "List #1 Sum: ";
    add(head);

    cout << endl << "List #2 Sum: ";
    add(head2);

    sort(head);
    cout << endl << "List #1 Sorted" << endl;
    print(head);

    sort(head2);
    cout << endl << "List #2 Sorted" << endl;
    print(head2);

    head3 = merge(head, head2);
    print(head3);
}
```

Comment: I think it's time to learn to use your debugger.

Comment: I have used it till the extent of confusion before I came for help on the forums.

Comment: in addition to just debugging, it's a good idea to *name* things. name operations. name data.

Comment: @Twigler What is confusing about a debugger?  You single step through your code, observe the variables, and whenever the program deviates from the plan you have written on paper, you've identified the problem.  At the very least, print the values of variables at strategic points in the program.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have tried doing all that, but there is nothing I can do to solve my problem... :(

Comment: How can you be confused?  You wrote the code, so debugging is going to be much easier for you than it is for us.

Answer (score 0):

For #3, you don't need a count. The code should also include checks for head == NULL, p1 == NULL before attempting to check p1->link, and it should check for p1->link == NULL before attempting to check p1->link->link. After adding these checks, to eliminate the count, just advance p1 two at a time: p1 = p1->link->link, while advancing p2 one at a time: p2 = p2->link. Once you reach the end of the list with p1->link or p1->link->link, then consider p2 to be a pointer to the last node of the first half of the list, and follow the given instructions on how to split the list.

For #4, the approach of recursively splitting the list into sub-lists is generically known as a [divide and conquer algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithms) (wiki link). This approach is used for top down merge sort, and although there are other approaches which are better suited (faster) to implementing merge sort with linked lists, I get the sense that the instructor probably wants you to follow the given hints.